# "Take care with" something

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expression-choice

Recently I had a deep discussion with an American person born and raised in the USA who said that when I say "take care with something" it makes absolutely no sense. That was said because she had never heard "take care with" (meaning "be careful") , but only "take care of" (which means something completely different from what I want to convey).

- May I use "Take care with the cars" instead of "Be careful with the cars", for instance?
- May I use "Take care!" instead of "Watch out!" ?

Or will it make no sense to USA North Americans? What about to British people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Take care' as a standalone statement is used as a farewell. I would not use it to say 'Watch out'.

'Take care with (x)' is a perfectly valid way to say 'Be careful with (x)'. - This is actually a valid definition from the  [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/care#care__29)

The answer to your first question is yes. The answer to your second question is no.

Comment: In Britain it's much the same, though perhaps the answer to the second question is 'Maybe'; maiden aunts and the like notoriously say "Oh, do take care!".

Comment: It's true that *"Take care!"* is usually an admonition to be careful over some extended period of time, and *"Watch out!"* usually applies to an *imminent* danger. But the dividing line is vague, so I don't really endorse your final sentence. Of course, things are further confused in recent years by the fact that more and more people just use *"Take care"* to mean nothing more than *"Goodbye"*.

Comment: I'd agree that it can be interchangeable with watch out in some sentences. Watch out as a stand alone sentence is used almost exclusively to draw attention to an imminent hazard, take care is never used in this context. I didn't claim they were never interchangeable, I specifically referred to their use as stand alone sentences.

Comment: So probably the second affirmation "no" should be changed to "maybe", right?"

Comment: No. "Take care" should never be used in place of "watch out". EDIT: If @FumbleFingers thinks that statement isn't entirely sound then there is a good chance it's not.